# Import Scapy.all

Tags: python, import, scapy

I want to know how to import scapy and use arping. I have tried import scapy.all and some others but has no seemed to work and I keep getting the error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                    
  File "network_scanner.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scapy.all import arping
ImportError: No module named scapy.all
```

This the code I am running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import arping


def scan(ip):
    arping(ip)


scan('10.0.2.1')
```

If someone could help me that would be amazing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named scapy.all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602880/importerror-no-module-named-scapy-all)

Comment: I put this into my code and I got this in return.

Comment: import os
print(os.sys.path)

os.sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

Comment: Result - ['/root/PycharmProjects/green-typer', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']

Comment: So then is scapy installed with pip on Python2.7 or some other version of python?

Comment: I think it is installed with python 3

Comment: Then that is your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210404/discussion-between-easton-antony-and-ross-jacobs).

Answer (score 0):

try to install scapy for ur python version. it seems like none scapy installed in your python lib.